# Password-Protect .XLS Excel files using Apache POI

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I am using Apache POI 3.11, which is supposed to support password-protecting Excel files (both XLS and XLSX types). I was easily able to get encrypting of the XLSX type to work properly using POI, but I have been unable to do this with the old XLS type. I have attempted this using the following code, but all it does is create a copy of the file without setting a password on it. As far as I can tell from the examples and API, this is how it is supposed to be done, but I cannot get it to work.

```
    HSSFWorkbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook(new FileInputStream(sourcePath));
    Biff8EncryptionKey.setCurrentUserPassword("potato");
    OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(destinationPath);
    wb.write(os);
    os.flush();
    os.close();
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated. As a last resort, I can perhaps use a different library, but I would prefer to use POI since this is what we use for everything else that is Excel-related.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the [Apache POI Encryption Supported Features Matrix](http://poi.apache.org/encryption.html#Supported+feature+matrix), HSSF only supports decrypting `.xls` files protected with a known password. It does not support encrypting them. (XSSF can work with both encrypting and decrypting `.xlsx` files)

Therefore, if you do want to support encrypting `.xls` files with Apache POI's HSSF, you'll need to [get involved with the project](http://poi.apache.org/guidelines.html) and then work on [submitting a patch](http://poi.apache.org/guidelines.html) for this missing piece of functionality!